# How to show values that has a suitable pair in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
---------------------------------------------
Id | TransactionId | Amount | Account| crdr | 
---------------------------------------------
1  |       1       | 100    | 11111  |   1  |
2  |       2       | 130    | 13133  |   1  |
3  |       1       | 100    | 12111  |   2  |
4  |       2       | 130    | 13233  |   2  |
5  |       2       | 110    | 12122  |   1  |
```

What I need to display is, show these records as pairs (I have grouped them by transactionid, Amount).

```
SELECT TransactionId ,Amount , Account, CrDr
FROM Table1 ORDER BY TransactionId  ASC,Amount  ASC, CrDr ASC
```

But I want to ignore the records which dont have a pair, as a Example for this above records set result should be like this

```
---------------------------------------------
TransactionId | Amount | Account| crdr | 
---------------------------------------------
      1       | 100    | 11111  |   1  |
      1       | 100    | 12111  |   2  |
      2       | 130    | 13133  |   1  |
      2       | 130    | 13233  |   2  |
```

Can someone suggest a solution for this.

Comment: How do you define a transaction has a pair? Your sample data has 5 rows, so how can the expected results have 4? If there's a (single) pair in your sample, surely the expected results would be 3 rows.

Comment: To be a pair it should have a the same Transaction Id and Amount, but the crdr value can be either 1 or 2. (BTW crdr column only contain 1 or 2) so if a one record's crdr value is 1 other should be 2

Comment: so In my sample data there isn't a suitable pair for the transaction Id - 5
because there isn't a row with the same amount and transaction  Id and a crdr value 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to ensure that another record exists with the same `TransactionId` and `Amount`:

```
SELECT TransactionId ,Amount , Account, CrDr
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table1 t1
    WHERE 
        t.id <> t1.id 
        AND t.TransactionId = t1.TransactionId
        AND t.Amount = t1.Amount
)
ORDER BY TransactionId  ASC,Amount  ASC, CrDr ASC
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=471040738b7ba4eb553727a6cedada9c)**:

```
TransactionId | Amount | Account | CrDr
------------: | -----: | ------: | ---:
            1 |    100 |   11111 |    1
            1 |    100 |   12111 |    2
            2 |    130 |   13133 |    1
            2 |    130 |   13233 |    2
```

Comment: `EXISTS` seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [Id] INT
    ,[TransactionId] INT
    ,[Amount] INT
    ,[Account] INT 
    ,[crdr] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Id], [TransactionId], [Amount], [Account], [crdr])
VALUES (1, 1, 100, 11111, 1)
      ,(2, 2, 130, 13133, 1)
      ,(3, 1, 100, 12111, 2)
      ,(4, 2, 130, 13233, 2)
      ,(5, 2, 110, 12122, 1);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*)  OVER (PARTITION BY [TransactionId], [Amount]) AS [Count]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE [Count] = 2
ORDER BY TransactionId  ASC,Amount  ASC, CrDr ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This this simplest solution of this problem

```
;with cte
as
(
    select TransactionId, Amount
    from Table1
    group by TransactionId, Amount
    having count(*) > 1
)
select * 
from Table1 t
inner join cte c on t.TransactionId = c.TransactionId and t.Amount = c.Amount
```

Comment: You want `select t.*` instead of `select *`.